# Displaying results based on different selection in sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently working on Microsoft SQL Server 2008. My question is: I have 5 conditions represented by parameters `@rep`, `@name`, `@work`, `@year`, `@seg`. How do I write a query that will display the result if I only fill up certain conditions=? And then I have a query that will count total number of visit. For example,

```
DECLARE @Rep varchar(100)
DECLARE @Name varchar(100)
DECLARE @Work varchar (100)
DECLARE @Year int
DECLARE @Seg int

SET @RepCode = ''
SET @Name = 'SYED'
SET @Work = ''
SET @Year = '2014'
SET @Seg = ''
```

I want the result to display the result for `syed` with year 2014 and the rep, work, and his seg. I tried this but it didn't work out.

```
if @Rep IS NOT NULL
    SELECT Id, Name, Work, YEAR, Rep 
    FROM #SalesRepVisit
    WHERE Rep = @Rep
ELSE 
   if @Name IS NOT NULL
      SELECT Id, Name, Work, YEAR, Rep 
      FROM #SalesRepVisit
      WHERE Name = @Name
   ELSE
      if @Work IS NOT NULL
         SELECT Id, Name, Work, YEAR, Rep 
         FROM #SalesRepVisit
         WHERE Work = @Work
      ELSE
          if @Year IS NOT NULL
             SELECT Id, Name, Work, YEAR, Rep
             FROM #SalesRepVisit
             WHERE YEAR = @Year
          ELSE
             if @Seg IS NOT NULL
                SELECT Id, Name, Work, YEAR, Rep 
                FROM #SalesRepVisit
                WHERE Seg = @Seg
```

To count the total number of visit I have this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Id as Id,
    Name as Customername,
    Rep As Repcode,
    (Select COUNT(*)  from #SalesRepVisit where Month = 1 and Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name AND Work = @Work and YEAR = @Year)as 'January',
    (Select COUNT(*)  from #SalesRepVisit where Month = 2 and Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name AND Work = @Work and YEAR = @Year)as 'February',
    (Select COUNT(*)  from #SalesRepVisit where Month = 3 and Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name AND Work = @Work and YEAR = @Year)as 'March' ,
    (Select COUNT(*)  from #SalesRepVisit where Month = 4 and Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name AND Work = @Work and YEAR = @Year)as 'April',
    (Select COUNT(*)  from #SalesRepVisit where Month = 5 and Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name AND Work = @Work and YEAR = @Year)as 'May',
    (Select COUNT(*)  from #SalesRepVisit where Month = 6 and Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name AND Work = @Work and YEAR = @Year)as 'June',
    (Select COUNT(*)  from #SalesRepVisit where Month = 7 and Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name AND Work = @Work and YEAR = @Year)as 'July',
    (Select COUNT(*)  from #SalesRepVisit where Month = 8 and Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name AND Work = @Work and YEAR = @Year)as 'August',
    (Select COUNT(*)  from #SalesRepVisit where Month = 9 and Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name AND Work = @Work and YEAR = @Year)as 'September',
    (Select COUNT(*)  from #SalesRepVisit where Month = 10 and Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name AND Work = @Work and YEAR = @Year)as 'October',
    (Select COUNT(*)  from #SalesRepVisit where Month = 11 and Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name AND Work = @Work and YEAR = @Year)as 'November',
    (Select COUNT(*)  from #SalesRepVisit where Month = 12 and Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name AND Work = @Work and YEAR = @Year)as 'December',
    Work as Work,
    YEAR as Year
FROM #SalesRepVisit
WHERE 
    Rep = @Rep and Name = @Name  AND Work = @Work AND YEAR = @Year
```

The query doesn't display anything. I want the query to display the results of 'syed' with his name, rep, work, seg, and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improved Answer of [@Radar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3950946/radar)

In the `Where` condition we can use `Case` statement

```
SELECT Id,
       Name,
       SUM ( CASE WHEN Month =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'January',
       SUM ( CASE WHEN Month =2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'February',
       ...
       ...
FROM   #SalesRepVisit
where  ( Rep  = Case When IsNull(@RepCode,'') ='' then Rep else @RepCode end)
   AND ( Name = Case When IsNull(@Name,'')='' then Name else @Name end)
   AND ( Work = Case When IsNull(@Work,'') ='' then Work else @Work end)
   AND ( YEAR = Case When IsNull(@Year,'') ='' then YEAR else @Year end)
GROUP BY Id, Name
```

Answer (score 1):

you are setting default value to empty string and comparing with NOT NULL as empty string is NOT NULL, search is done for empty string.

First part to get results when only filters condition is met

```
SELECT Id,Name,Work,YEAR,Rep from #SalesRepVisit
WHERE  ( @RepCode ='' OR Rep  = @RepCode  )
   AND ( @Name    ='' OR Name = @Name     )
   AND ( @Work    ='' OR Work = @Work     )
   AND ( @Year    ='' OR YEAR = @Year     )
```

To count the number of visits in each Month based on the filter criteria, you can use `case based aggregation`

```
SELECT Id,
       Name,
       SUM ( CASE WHEN Month =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'January',
       SUM ( CASE WHEN Month =2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'February',
       ...
       ...
FROM   #SalesRepVisit
where  ( @RepCode ='' OR Rep  = @RepCode  )
   AND ( @Name=''     OR Name = @Name     )
   AND ( @Work =''    OR Work = @Work     )
   AND ( @Year =''    OR YEAR = @Year     )
GROUP BY Id, Name
```

Comment: the result still doesn't display anything.. @radar

Comment: @SKJ, sample data would help identify the issue. i don't see issue with query

Comment: what do you mean sample data? @radar. is it like the table containing  all the data?? sorry if i am asking too much question.

Comment: i have another one more question regarding this. this query produce the result for all the data. how if i only want the result depending on my condition. for example, let say i put  the name 'syed' so i only want the result for 'syed' only and not for everyone. how do i do that? thanks again. :)